# How to use getStaticPaths dynamically in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have 3 blog categories which I need to paginate static pages for each of them . The problem is the number of pages may vary and I can't get access to anything on what category needs to be fetched in getStaticPaths .

The project folder structure is like this :
[image]

My code is like this :

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async (props) => {
  
    // const { category } = props.params;  // Cant Access to dynamic category name from the url

    const blogs = await client.getEntries({
      content_type: "blog",
     // "fields.category": category, // Cant Access to dynamic category name from the url
    });

    let pages;
    const howmany = blogs.total / 12;
    pages = Math.ceil(howmany / 1) * 1;
    let paths = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
      paths.push({
        params: { page: `${i + 1}` },
      });
    }

  return {
    paths ,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { category, page } = params;

  const limit = 2;
  let skip;
  if (JSON.parse(page) === 1) {
    skip = 0;
  } else {
    skip = JSON.parse(page) * limit - limit;
  }
  const blogs = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "blog",
    limit: limit,
    skip: skip,
    "fields.category": category,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      page: JSON.parse(page),
      blogs: blogs.items,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

I need to get access to dynamic category string from url in getStaticPaths so I can get the exact number of blogposts for that specific category but couldn't have access to anything at all .

How can I fix this problem ? Is there a workaround to fix this ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think it would be easier to just have a blog/categories/[category] path, that way you will only have one dynamic segment in your path, but of course that's just a personal opinion. Is this a valid approach in your case?

Comment: @ivanatias Well how can get the category in getStaticPaths so I could fetch that category data and calculate the pages and return the paths ?

Comment: You could fetch all the categories in your `getStaticPaths` and then, in your `getStaticProps` fetch all the posts for each particular category. As for the pagination, you could store all the posts of a category in a state and manage the number of pages from that total number of posts stored in that array state. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: One option is to use Catch all routes https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes and specify all valid category/blogpost combinations in getStaticPaths

Comment: @ivanatias Thanks for your comment . There is only one problem with this solution you've suggested , I need to return the paths in ```getStaticPaths``` and the paths prop is calculated for each category separately , so what should I return in paths for specific category page If I fetch all categories and calculate their pages ?

Comment: @ChristianHagelid Thanks for your comment , How should I return the paths in getStaticPaths If I go with this method you've suggested ?

Comment: can you confirm if you are trying to render a blog post page or a blog category page (or both)?

Comment: @ChristianHagelid I'm trying to paginate for each category of blogs for example category mutation has 24 posts , category diseases have 20 posts and this page will render the blogs of one category not all of em .

Comment: ok so I assume you are trying to render `/blog/<category` pages. For example, `/blog/diseases`. You will need to change `[page].tsx` to `index.tsx`. @ivanatias's solution should work just fine for this scenario. `getStaticPaths` will return an array of category names and in `getStaticProps` you can fetch page 1 of blog posts for each respective category. Then you can for example create an API endpoint to fetch subsequent pages for a category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the help of [Ivan atias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17195992/ivanatias) [Christian Hagelid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202/christian-hagelid) and generated all categories pages in getStaticPaths and returned the final path like this :

```
 let paths = [];

  newCategories.forEach((eachCategory: any) => {
    let pages;
    const howmany = eachCategory.posts.length / limit;
    pages = Math.ceil(howmany / 1) * 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
      paths.push({
        params: { page: `${i + 1}`, category: eachCategory.category },
      });
    }
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
```